# Firebase Firestore Read Count?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Firebase Firestore costs based on number of read operations. If I download a higher level document that has more then one sub-documents ( like Downloading a parent node that has more than one child node in Firebase Realtime Database.) then will it be considered as a single read or multiple read? I have not found any point about this in the documentation. Please explain?

Answer (score 1):

Firestore queries are always shallow, and do not consider documents in subcollection.  The only way to query for documents in subcollecitons is to target that subcollection with a separate query.

It does **not** work like Realitme Database, which gives you all child nodes with a parent node.